# How to define an interface in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm working on a C++ class which provides an abstraction of BSD sockets for networking. I want to define an interface `ISocket` which is implemented by `CSocket` and `MockSocket` (the latter for unit testing). I know that I need to define the methods that I want implementing classes to provide as pure virtual, i.e.

```
class ISocket {
public:
  virtual int Socket(int domain, int type, int protocol) = 0;
};
```

What I'm worried about is whether a class of type `ISocket` can be instantiated. My instincts tell me that any class with at least one pure virtual method is an abstract class (i.e. interface) and cannot be instantiated, but I have a niggling worry in the back of my mind that I need to do something about the auto-generated constructors and destructor that the C++ compiler will provide ([Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) is both a gift--when you remember everything you read in it--and a curse--when you don't).

Am I doing this correctly, or is there a best practise for defining interfaces in C++ that I'm not following here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should declare a `virtual` destructor; otherwise you'll get into undefined behaviour if you try to invoke `delete` on a pointer-to-interface.  There are no such issues with constructors.

Oh, and you are correct that it is not possible to instantiate an object of a class with a pure-virtual.

Comment: My implementing classes have no data, they simply wrap the C standard library functions that I need for networking. In this case, do I still need to explicitly define a virtual destructor? I realise that I would certainly need to do so if my derived classes had any data members, but it seems silly to provide a destructor here just to stop C++ from doing so. :)

Comment: @Josh: They may not have any data (or other resources) now, but can you guarantee that they won't in the future?  Also, technically, invoking `delete` on a pointer-to-base without a virtual destructor is undefined behaviour.

Comment: OK, good points all. I'll just sigh at C++'s occasionally silliness and Do the Right Thing. ;)

Comment: An alternative to a virtual destructor, in some circumstances, is a protected non-virtual destructor, to prevent deleting via a base-class pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> My instincts tell me that any class with at least one pure virtual method is an abstract class (i.e. interface) and cannot be instantiated

Your instincts are correct on this one. Types with at least one pure virtual function can't be instantiated and will generate a compiler error.

Comment: In fact, you can get an instance of pure virtual class during construction or destruction stage. In that case, you may end up calling a default implementation of the pure virtual function, which usually does nothing but aborts the application. That's why you (almost) never call virtual functions from constructors and/or destructors.

Comment: @Vlad: If you've read "Effective C++", you'll never want to call a virtual function in ctor/dtor, only if you want Scott Meyers to hunt you down with an Axe. Or a chainsaw. :)

Comment: @Xeo: That's exactly what I said. However, sometimes you need to do that, and if you know what you are doing, it will work without consequences.

Comment: @Xeo: One great tip I got from "Effective C++" or elsewhere is to never do **anything** in a constructor or destructor that can fail. :) Of course, sometimes you need to allocate memory, which is hard to avoid.

Comment: @Josh: I just read it (literally hours ago) and my favorite is to never throw in a destructor, not even throwing up. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing correct:An abstract class is a class that is designed to be specifically used as a base class. An abstract class contains at least one pure virtual function. You cannot instantiate a virtual class.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in thinking that any class with a pure virtual method is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Personally I tend to add a protected destructor to most of my interfaces as in many/most cases I don't want the code that uses the interface to be able to destroy it. Alternatively you should add a public virtual destructor (not pure, with an empty body!) so that the object can be deleted via the interface pointer and the correct destructors will be called.

Comment: The protected destructor is a great idea!